# Proving that $\int 0 d\mu=0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

While looking for a clean proof of $\int 0 d\mu=0$, I encountered a difficulty.

Consider $0$ as a function between $(X,\Sigma, \mu)$ and $({\mathbb R}, \mathcal B)$.

Since $0=1_\emptyset+0\cdot 1_X$, $\int 0 d\mu=\mu(\emptyset)+0\cdot\mu(X)=0\cdot\mu(X)$

Why should $0\cdot\mu(X)$ be $0$ ? Is that some convention ?

It's certainly true when $\mu(X)<\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In measure theory, espacially when defining the integral, for clearer readiability, one uses the convention, that 
$$ 0 \cdot \infty = 0 $$
So the answer is: Yes, that's some convention.

Comment: It not *merely* a convention, though: It is the only convention that makes sense in the integration theory setting. Almost too many theorems to enumerate might fail without this convention. But, as with all such conventions, it comes at a price: One has to be a bit more careful in limit arguments involving $0\cdot\infty$.